# How to set chrome.alarms.getAll callback to a variable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use the chrome.alarms.getAll() method to get back the number of alarms there are into a variable I can use, but I am having trouble doing it because of the scope it's in.  I'm not quite sure how to get it out, can anyone help?  Code that's not working:

```
function query() {
  var count; 
  chrome.alarms.getAll(function(alarms) { count = alarms.length; }); 
  return count; 
}

var numAlarms = query(); //undefined
```

numAlarms returns undefined, even though I have 2 alarms and can see it when I use

```
chrome.alarms.getAll(function(alarms) { console.log(alarms) };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `callback` function for `query`

```
function query(callback) {
    var count; 
    chrome.alarms.getAll(function(alarms) { callback(alarms.length) }); 
}

query(function(count) {
    var numAlarms = count;
});
```